# Перечисление указателей на функции, как? С++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Перечисление указателей на функции, как? С++

Не могу найти инфы, возможно ли это, если да, то как?

```
void DispClear(void);

enum allowedFlags {(&DispClear)};

void DelayFlag(allowedFlags Flag, word Time)
{

}

void DispClear(void)
{

}
```

DelayFlag должна принимать только разрешенные enum указатели на функции.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под слово «перечисление»? Приведите гипотетический пример кода и какой должен быть его смысл.

Comment: Выполнено.(минимальная длинна)

Comment: Уточните версию стандарта. Начиная с версии С++11, появились интересные решения вашей проблемы - анонимные функции.

Comment: Насколько я знаю поддержка С++11 присутствует. Но как я откоментил ниже, самого C++ я не знаю, а пишу на нем для лучшей защиты типов данных. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, такое невозможно.

`enum` может базироваться только на целочисленных типах.

Если вы хотите позволить в некоторых обстоятельствах выполнять только функции из заранее заготовленного набора, посмотрите в сторону классов с приватным конструктором.

Пример:

```
class C
{
    friend class C1;
    friend class C2;
protected:
    C() {}

public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    static void Init();
};

class C1 : public C
{
    friend class C;
    C1() {}
public:
    void f() { cout << "C1" << endl; }
};

class C2 : public C
{
    friend class C;
    C2() {}
public:
    void f() { cout << "C2" << endl; }
};


C* c1;
C* c2;

void C::Init()
{
    c1 = new C1();
    c2 = new C2();
}
```

Единственные два экземпляра класса `C` лежат в `c1` и `c2`.

```
void DelayFlag(C* pc, word Time)
{
    pc->f();
}
```

Comment: Можно ли решить вопрос преобразованиями типов? Указатель в слово, потом обратно?

Извиняюсь за каламбур.

Comment: @ReasonX перефразируя бабку из ролика про интернет скажу - <i>даром</i> не нужна такая архитектура. В этом нет ни капли смысла и это потенциально опасно. Для этого придуманы классы.

Comment: я пишу для мк, С++ исключительно для защиты от косяков с типами данных. Классы мне жирновато будет.

Comment: @ReasonX 
1. Подумайте об использовании C++11 и шаблонов.
2. После компиляции, от классов в программе не останется и следа, при определенных условиях.

Comment: пффф, ток проблема в том что С++ я не знаю. Ладно спасибо за помощь. Если проблема встанет остро, буду разбираться. Пока попробую на собственной внимательности выехать.

Comment: @ReasonX: Даже если это и технически возможно, я бы так не делал. Грязные трюки наподобие `reinterpret_cast` (а вам нужен именно он) сводят на нет всю «безопасность».

Comment: @ReasonX: Но я бы _порекомендовал_ подучить C++. Писать на языке, не зная его — опасный путь, вы можете попасть в ловушку, вовсе не подозревая об этом. (Особенно это относится к небезопасным нативным языкам наподобие C++.)

Answer (score 2):

Перечисления могут содержать лишь целочисленные именованные константы. Поэтому ваша идея некорректная.

Вам нужно просто объявить какой-нибудь контейнер указателей на функцию, как, например, массив, и его использовать.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

int square( int x )
{
    return x * x;
}

int cube( int x )
{
    return x * x * x;
}

int factorial( int x )
{
    return x < 2 ? 1 : x * factorial( x - 1 );
}

std::ostream & operation( int f( int ), int x, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    return os << f( x ) << ' ';
}    

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    int ( *fn[] )( int ) = { square, cube, factorial }; 

    for ( int x : a )
    {
        std::cout << x << ": ";
        for ( int ( *f )( int ) : fn ) std::cout << f( x ) << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : a )
    {
        std::cout << x << ": ";
        for ( int ( *f )( int ) : fn ) operation( f, x );
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
1: 1 1 1 
2: 4 8 2 
3: 9 27 6 
4: 16 64 24 
5: 25 125 120 
6: 36 216 720 

1: 1 1 1 
2: 4 8 2 
3: 9 27 6 
4: 16 64 24 
5: 25 125 120 
6: 36 216 720
```

В этой программе функция `operation` имеет первым параметром функцию с типом `int( int )`. Вы можете передавать в качестве аргумента для этого параметра любую функцию, имеющую указанный тип, например, последовательно из контейнера указателей на функцию, как это показано в программе, где используется массив указателей на функции.

Comment: Спастбо, навели меня на мысль.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось как то так, во всяком случае, оно компилируется.

Есть какие нибудь камни?

```
#define FQS 16  //Flag Queue Size

void Func0(void);
void Func1(void);
void Func2(void);

const p_VoidFuncPointer allowedFuncArray[16] = {Func0,Func1,Func2};

enum allowedFunc{Call0,Call1,Call2};

volatile struct {
    allowedFunc     Function;
    word            Time;
    }FlagQueue[FQS];

byte IndexCounter = 0;

void setFlagDelayed(allowedFunc Flag, word Time)
{

}

void TC0Interrupt(void)//TEST FUNC
{
    p_VoidFuncPointer CallFunc;
    for(byte counter; counter<IndexCounter;counter++)
    {

        FlagQueue[counter].Time--;
        if (FlagQueue[counter].Time == 0)
        {
            CallFunc = allowedFuncArray[FlagQueue[counter].Function];
            (CallFunc)();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не инициализируете `byte counter`. Это нехорошо.

Comment: Не видно, как вы определяете `allowedFunc`. И непонятно, зачем вам `enum allowedFunc`, а не просто `unsigned int`: что то, что другое надо синхронизировать с размером массива `allowedFuncArray`.

Comment: А ещё вы не проверяете `CallFunc` на `nullptr` перед вызовом.

Comment: Да наскоро писал, byte counter забыл, виноват. 

"Не видно, как вы определяете allowedFunc"

Дак он вроде же как тип данных определяется, если его после enum писать?

Comment: А. вижу, сорри. Тогда плохо то, что вам приходится поддерживать синхронизацию между `allowedFunc` и `allowedFuncArray` вручную, компилятор не предупредит вас, если вы сделаете ошибку.

Comment: Это да, но по другому у меня знаний не хватает.

Comment: И мне в любом случае городить под каждый пункт массива отдельную функцию, так что это еще не самое зло.

Comment: По поводу nullptr, возможно вы правы. Но у меня тут по логике программы они никак не может таковым оказаться. А если окажется, уж лучше все к чертям полетит и это будет видно, ибо индикации ошибок я не планировал.

Comment: Ну. тогда я бы отказался от enum'а, раз он всё равно не помогает, перешёл на `byte` и проверял бы его в рантайме. (Ну или попробовал бы таки придумать что-то в compile time.)